# Maintaining the Query String with htaccess rewrite

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have an htaccess that redirects any url except urls in 3 specific folders to a php file which handles displaying the page:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks  
RewriteEngine On  
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/app [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/templates [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/downloads [NC]
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \ /+([^\ \?]*)
RewriteRule (.*)$ ./app/index.php?url=%1 [L,B]
```

The problem is, however, any query info in the url is lost. I was wondering if it would be possible to retain that.

for example:

```
mysite.com/test?page=1 would become /app/index.php?page=1&url=test
```

rather than (Which is what happens now):

```
mysite.com/test?page=1 becomes /app/index.php?url=test
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need a `QSA` flag here:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks  
RewriteEngine On  
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/app [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/templates [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/downloads [NC]
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \ /+([^\ \?]*)
RewriteRule (.*)$ ./app/index.php?url=%1 [L,B,QSA]
```

`QSA` (Query String Append) flag preserves existing query parameters while adding a new one.